# Excel if cell contains text then use text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would need to standardize the name of certain sites e.g. Sydney Office, NSW Office, Orange -> should all be Sydney.Same for other sites e.g. Brisbane office, QLD Exp -> should be Brisbane.

I am able to execute nested IF. Please suggest the modification in below written formula.

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("*Syd*",S2,1),"Sydney"),"No")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the scope?  How many standard site names?  How many alternate names?  Where is all of this located and in what kind of layout?  Is every current site name always in a consistent form?

Answer (score 2):

You can nest IFs by putting a new IF function as the previous one's if_false
argument. For example:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Syd",S3,1),"Sydney",IF(SEARCH("Bri",S3,1),"Brisbane")),"No")
```

Alternatively, I recommend another table with the names and a lookup function such as VLOOKUP. Please check below the Sample table:

```
Actual Value        |   Standardize Value
====================|====================
Sydney Office       |   Sydney
NSW Office          |   Sydney
Orange              |   Sydney
Brisbane office     |   Brisbane
QLD Exp             |   Brisbane
```

Comment: Can you take this across the finish line by including an example working solution?  As is, this is more of a hint for the OP to research and create their own solution (which might be more appropriate as a comment).

Comment: I've tried the nested option suggested by @fezzikMontonya but the nested IF doesn't seem to apply

Comment: Did formula return wrong value or error?

Comment: It returns a No on the second IF although the string is present

Comment: @Mik Sorry, my fault. Please try formula below. I wrapped SEARCH functions with IFERROR(...,FALSE)    `=IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Syd",S3,1),FALSE),"Sydney",IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Bri",S3,1),FALSE),"Brisbane")),"No")`